# Thank You Page Layout Differs on User Logged In Status

Tags: login

I have downloadable products on my site.

In WordPress after placing a order for some reason when I am logged in the layout appears like this and when I am not the download button and billing address is not showing up.

This is how it appears when a user is loggedin to Wordpress - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YVqJ.png

This is how it appears if a user is **NOT** logged into Wordpress - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qef68.jpg

How can I ensure the Download button and billing address appears for both logged and non logged in users?

I guess it has something to do with order-downloads.php or order-details.php files in Woocommerce templates but not sure what exactly and would appreciate the help to ensure the same layout appears on both ends or to bypass the Wordpress restrictions

Comment: Did you consider what this will cause? One user can buy the product and than share the link with X people. Each person that received the link will be able to download that product. Is this really what you want to happen?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast thats not what I want, the problem is that the download button only appears when users are logged into Wordpress, users can purchase directly without choosing to create a account (guest checkout), in this case the download button isnt appearing, so I would like to fix that.